# Encoding problems when requesting Google suggestions

Tags: objective-c, unicode, encoding, nsstring, nsjsonserialization

I'm trying to get [Google Suggestions](http://shreyaschand.com/blog/2013/01/03/google-autocomplete-api/) to work for Greek but I get an error if the suggestions contain characters other than english.

If the query is "*magni*" for example the response will contain a greek word "*μαγνήσιο*" as a suggestion. [Try it](http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?q=magni&client=toolbar&hl=el)

The error is:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=261 "The file “search” couldn’t
>   be opened using text encoding Unicode (UTF-8)."
>   UserInfo={NSURL=http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?q=magni&client=toolbar&hl=el,
>   NSStringEncoding=4}

The method is:

```
+ (NSArray *)suggestionsForQuery:(NSString *)query
{
    query = [query stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];

    NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?q=%@&client=toolbar&hl=%@", query, @"el"]; // el is for greek

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSString *XMLString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLString] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

    if (error) {

        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
    }
    else {

        // ...
    }
}
```

I tried:

1. Setting the encoding to NSUTF16StringEncoding but I got some Chinese characters.
2. NSJSONSerialization by setting "toolbar=firefox" to get a JSON response but I got the same error.

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unable to convert data to
>   string around character 40." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Unable to
>   convert data to string around character 40.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: `stringWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error:` returns encoding `0x80000207` and a string that's Greek to me.

Comment: How? I'm still getting this error: "The file “search” couldn’t be opened because the text encoding of its contents can’t be determined."

Comment: Does `-[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]` work?

Comment: Yes, no problems.

Comment: Can you upload the project you created for this just to make sure its not a weird bug from my side?

Comment: I copied your code, added `NSStringEncoding encoding;` and replaced `encoding:NSISOLatin2StringEncoding` by `usedEncoding:&encoding`.

Comment: That's exactly what I did: [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLString] usedEncoding:&encoding error:&error]; and I got the "encoding can't be determined" error!

Comment: Even made a new project just for this, still doesn't work...

Comment: Could it be that "NSAppTransportSecurity" is responsible for this?

Comment: I don't know but if `dataWithContentsOfURL` works it should be ok I think.

Comment: Did you try using https?

Comment: Yes, no luck...